Create a df column from data of two different dataframes
I have the following piece of code that runs flawlessly:
def AddAvgPowerToIntervalsDf(intervalsDf, samplesDf):
avgPowerList = []
for i, row in intervalsDf.iterrows():
    avgPowerList.append(samplesDf.loc[(samplesDf["SECS"] >= row["START"]) & (samplesDf["SECS"] < row["STOP"]), "WATTS"].mean())
    
intervalsDf["AvgPower"] = avgPowerList
intervalsDf["AvgPower"] = intervalsDf["AvgPower"].round().astype("Int64")

return(intervalsDf)

Could anybody suggest how it would be possible avoid using iterrows? (I hate using it ;-)).
Please, note: the two dataframes are of completely different sizes.
Here are examples of the two input df's:
print(df1)
       START  STOP
0      0     6
1      6     9
2      9    10

print(df2)

       SECS  WATTS
0      0     90
1      1     97
2      2    116
3      3    127
4      4    123
5      5    110
6      6    119
7      7    113
8      8    111
9      9    114
10    10    117

Please note that there is an operation performed on the column of df2 between the values indicated in df1.
AddAvgPowerToIntervalDf(df1, df2)

       START  STOP  AvgPower
0      0     6       110
1      6     9       114
2      9    10       114

Thanks again.

Your question lacks a [mre] of the data, but it looks like a merge between start/end (for which there are many duplicates on SO)
